# Copy vertex groups from old object to new object(2.8)

Tags: python, vertex-groups

I have to modify new orientation and for this i think to make a copy from old object to new object, but not undertand if is possible to copy vertex grup from old object/ mesh to new object/ mesh :

```
 old_obj = bpy.data.objects['My old obj name']

 mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('My new obj name')
 new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('My new obj name', mesh)
 new_obj.data = old_obj.data.copy()
```

Comment: Do you need to use python? Under the `+-` buttons next to the shape key list is a menu that has `Transfer shape key` that will copy the active shapekey from a selected object to the active object.

Comment: @Sambler, sorry i need a script in python